# Private Root CA - certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)

Tags: ssl

I've been googling for days and reading everything and doing it again and again but not sure what's going on and I need some help because I'm getting crazy so I could be doing something stupid.

I have a Private CA. This is a Linux box I used to generate certs and sign them using this Root CA.

I have a requirement to use encrypted LDAP and I need to verify the certificate. GitLab, SSSD, etc... has this option so I'm trying to configure and use it.

I generated a new cert called secureldap.domain.com using my private CA. For GitLab when I run the ldap check I got this error:
"Exception: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)"

I've added the secureldap.domain.com cert to /etc/gitlab/trusted-certs. I've added the Root CA cert to the same folder. I've created a new file where I have the secureldap first and the Root CA at the end, but no luck.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong or missing here. Any help is very welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After days reviewing everything I found it had some junk in the MMC --> Certificate --> Service --> Personal

I had to remove the old certificate was there and I had to add the new one here. Interesting I did not see any documentation saying about having to put the cert also in the Service --Personal.

Better take note of this.